# Landing Page not populating with subscriber data

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I'm just getting started with Landing Pages to create a custom preference center using ampscript/api calls.  I've coded the page to display subscriber data upon first view.  When I look at the "subscriber preview" everything works fine and subscriber data populates the form.  But when I go to the link of the ACTUAL landing page no data populates the form.  I have appended URL variables.  I have sent myself an email that included the landing page link.  Outside of the "subscriber preview" no data is being pulled.

What am I missing here?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you've coded your link on the email, it could be that you're not using the correct format/Ampscript to pass the subscriber data over to your landing page.

You would want to setup your link to the landing page similar to the below.  Below link also provides some further AMPScript functions to accomplish this.  The "77777" below is the Landing Page ID that you can find when viewing properties of the page.  Hope this helps!

```
<p>
<a title="MyPage" href="%%=MicrositeURL(77777)=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">Click to unsubscribe</a>
</p>
```

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/

Comment: What @Jeremy said is correct.  Utilizing the MicrositeURL() function will wrap the link with the encoded subscriber attribute data (or sending data extension columns, depending on how you're sending).   In SSJS you can then retrieve the attribute values using the Attribute.GetValue() function.

Comment: Bingo! Not sure how I was going to figure that out without your help. Much appreciated.